# Машина состояний(FSM) в Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Есть некий класс,с набором стейтов

```py
class CellarImport(StatesGroup):
    item = State()
    volume = State()
    count = State()
```

И дело в том что при попытке пройтись по хендлерам через стейты с помощью соответсвующей команды

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['add'], state=None)
async def enter_item(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Как назовёте позицию?')
    await CellarImport.item.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=CellarImport.item)
async def enter_volume(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(answer1=answer)
    await message.answer('Объём?')
    await CellarImport.volume.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=CellarImport.volume)
async def enter_volume(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(answer2=answer)
    await message.answer('Количество?')
    await CellarImport.count.set()
```

Выскакивает некая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как это исправить?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы не указали хранище `storage`

### Описание

aiogram поддерживает работу как с временным локальным хранилищем (оперативная память), так и с множеством внешних (redis, memcache, mongodb, rethinkdb и т.д.)

### Пример

Для подключения локального хранилища:

1. Создайте объект хранилища:

```py
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

storage = MemoryStorage()
```

2. При создании объекта класса `Dispatcher` передайте объект хранилищя в параметр `storage`

```py
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

### Важно!

Хранилище `MemoryStorage` будет терять все данные после перезагрузи приложения. Для независимого хранения данных используйте внешние хранилища. Способ их подключения отличается только необходимостью передачи настроек при создании объекта.

```py
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.redis import RedisStorage2

storage = RedisStorage2(
    host=REDIS_HOST, 
    port=REDIS_PORT,
    db=REDIS_DB,
    password=REDIS_PASSWORD,
    # и т.д.
)
```